# Creating Session in Rails Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, helper

I have the following code in my application helper.

```
  route = ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(current_uri)
  controller = route[:controller]
  action = route[:action]
  session['route']<< [controller.to_s,action.to_s]
```

I get the following error 
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<

Some quick logging and I see that controller and action work just fine.  Can you not create sessions in helpers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the session to hold an array of these arrays (a "stack of routes" if you will), then you first need to make sure that `session[:route]` is non-nil:

```
session[:route] ||= []
session[:route] << [controller.to_s, action.to_s]
```

Otherwise, simply assign it:

```
session[:route] = [controller.to_s, action.to_s]
```

Also, you should use symbols as hash keys, not strings.

Comment: You can shorten the first `if` statement to `session[:route] ||= []`

Answer (score 0):

You can but the way you are doing it is wrong. When this code executes for the first time it gets session['route'] as nil. You can do

```
session['route'] = [controller.to_s, action.to_s]
```

Although, what are you trying to do here? I suppose there is a better of achieving what you intend to do here.